# Maximum HTTP post size in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

what is the maximum http post body size for the TFX serving?

I can not find it anywhere in the https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest documentation nor in other parts of documentation. Most web servers have some default maximal value, which can be configured, but I have not found anything.
I have features of varying sizes, some of them being over 1GB large, so I want to know what is the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/util/net_http/server/internal/evhttp_request.cc), it seems that tfx is using http service implemented by libevent library.

Then I read the libevent code, the default body size is `((((ev_uint64_t)0xffffffffUL) << 32) | 0xffffffffUL)` on 64-bit systems and `((ev_uint32_t)0xffffffffUL)` on 32-bit systems. In other words, the largest unsigned integer. (You can search `evhttp_set_max_body_size` in libevent code.)